# How to add search filter in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-activity, searchview, android-search

hello everyone im new here and new to android development ,im trying to modify this project [Click HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text)

i want to filter cities with search widget in action bar ,however i have managed to add it in action bar but i don't know who get it working to filter cites names .

here is my menu.xml code

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="vatsag.samples.weatherdisplay"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".WeatherActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_weather" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_weather">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Activity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();


        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        if(null!=searchManager ) {   
         searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        }
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply sir ,i have added it in my activity but its not searching anything .thanks anyway